# Symfony Doctrine update query fail

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

My code is:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("UPDATE AppBundle:Project u SET u.name=1, u.key=?2, u.leader=?3 WHERE u.id = ?4");
$query->setParameter(1, $project->name);
$query->setParameter(2, $project->key);
$query->setParameter(3, $project->lead->name);
$query->setParameter(4, $project->id);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Now when I run it, it gives me a error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'EIAD', leader = 'fake.name' WHERE id = '12305'' at
>      line 1

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
I even tried with the Object update like:

```
$project->setname();
```

etc.

EDIT: Forgot to say the code is used in a self created command!

Comment: Show the results of $query->getSql();

Comment: I don't think it will solve the issue but you have `?` missing in `u.name=1`. Should be `u.name=?1`.

Comment: @JakubMatczak Forgotten but didn't solved the issue, same error still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Querybuilder. Example:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();     
$query = $em->getRepository(Project::class)->createQueryBuilder('')
            ->update(Project::class, 'u')

            ->set('u.name', ':name')
            ->set('u.key', ':key')
            ->set('u.leader', ':leader')
            ->setParameter('name', $project->name)
            ->setParameter('key', $project->key)
            ->setParameter('leader', $project->leader)

            ->where('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $project->id)
            ->getQuery();

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Well I now got an other error:

[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'AppBundle\Command\Project': Error: Class 'AppBundle\Command\Project' is not defined.



  [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
  UPDATE AppBundle\Command\Project u SET u.name = :name, u.key = :key, u.leader = :leader WHERE u.id = :id

Forgot to say that the code is used in a self created command

Comment: You need a use statement for Project or just go back to AppBundle:Project.

Comment: @Cerad Also tried it then I got the same error back: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'EIAD', leader = 'fake.name' WHERE id = '12305'' at line 1

Comment: key is a reserved mysql word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html Change the column name to something else.

Comment: @Cerad Woahh, totally forgotten! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The properties of Entities are private or protected. This means you cannot access them directly like this: `$project->name` you have to use the getters and setters like this: `$project->getName()`

Comment: $project is a external cURL request to an api that gives me a public object back. Nothing to do with the issue ;) See in the error that the values are filled in.